# distance between two increasing functions with same integral on the interval [0,1]?

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

The question is detailed in the picture below. It seems easy to get the geometric interpretation of the inequality as the intersection area between two increasing lines in the square of $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ is less than half. But how could it be proved or is there any hint? Should I look at the question merely as a calculus exercise or is there any other interpretations or methods to solve the proof from other points of view? for example the $L^1$ norm distance of function $f$ and $g$?

> [image: picture]